# Is postback mandatory for hidden fields to work?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, hidden-field

I wan't to know if a hidden field essentially need to have a postback to send or access its value to server side? 
for eg: if we have a hidden field x and it was set to some value in Javascript on client side. Can't we access this field on Server codebehind as soon as it set on client side without postback?

Comment: use ajax to access it on server side. whenever you write into your hidden field, you can use ajax to call the server side function. thats the only way without doing a full postback

Comment: Yeah, Thats fine. But my question is postback is mandatory for Hidden fields to serve the purpose right?

Comment: the answer to that would be yes. postback or a partial postback using ajax is mandatory for your hidden input value to be accessible on the server side

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to get the value from hidden field on server side without sending the post request, you can send the AJAX call. I believe we would need to have more details from you to give more specific answer.

Additionally your postback work might be missleading.
Hidden field needs to be inside  tag to send this to server. If you check the form tag you can manipulate the method attribute to send values with POST or GET request.

Comment: OK i am setting a value for hidden field on client side. Now based in this value, my logic on server event changes. There fore I am wondering if poatback is mandatory for hidden fields

Answer (score 0):

if you set the hidden field value at the client side script you can also send an Ajax request with the value to the server instead of getting the field value from the HTML DOM.
Example :

```
function setValue(fieldValue){
   $("#hiddenField").val(fieldValue);
   $.get( "/setfield?value="+fieldValue, function( data ) {
       //handle response data if any
   });
}
```

note that this specific solution requires JQuery, if necessary, you can achieve the same thing without it but it's more complicated.

Comment: We can't set any instance variables using this. I need to set an instance variable/Property so that I can use it in other methods of the Codebehind specific to that UserControl

Comment: Maybe you can pass a scope element (the UserControl's instance html DOM root element) to the function and do something like this : $(scopeElem).find('.hiddenField').val(fieldValue) and then send the UserControl instance id as well with the Ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Hidden Fields store the value in the page itself, hence do not use server resources.

Comment: Sry, I didn't get  What do you mean by "hence do not use server resources."

Comment: Hidden Field can be used to store a value at a page level. The value of the Hidden Field is sent along in the HTTP Form Collection along with the value of other controls.

Comment: Agreed, but even that need a Postback. I want a solution without a postback to set an instance variable based on which some logic in few methods of codebehind are dependent